# multi language create store view issue

Tags: magento2

I tried to create new store view in Magento 2.
I have already set `Website>Store>Store View(English)`

- Name : product-en
- Code : product_en
- Status : Enable
- Sort Order : 0

I wanted to create store view (Chinese) on the same level(in the same Store)

- Name : product-zh
- Code : product_zh
- Status : Enable
- Sort Order : 0

But I faced following issue.

**"Something went wrong while saving. Please review the error log."**[image]

Comment: could you please add error log ?

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for reply.
You mean the error log in server directory or public_html directory?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes at `public_html/var/log`, if there is any specific error.

Comment: Which log in ver/log should I specify?
connector.log
debug.log
exception.log
magento.cron.log
setup.cron.log
system.log
update.cron.log
update.log

Comment: I think `exception.log`

Comment: the comment of the bottom line in exception.log is following.
[2019-03-26 05:09:36] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: script_name in /home/sin55/public_html/pub/errors/processor.php on line 452 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: script_name in /home/sin55/public_html/pub/errors/processor.php on line 452 at /home/sin55/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

Comment: I think it is not related toy your error. You need to check all log

Comment: You mean I need to check all log inside exception.log?

Comment: I think .. yes :(

Comment: I tried to create new store view in dashboard again, and check exception.log. but no update there. so should I check other log?

Comment: you can do one thing, remove folder `var/log`, after that create store and check log.

Comment: oh, I see. I'll try to do it.

Comment: I tried to do it, and appeared some comments in system.log [2019-03-30 04:07:04] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /home/sin55/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 512
Trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'is_file() expec...', '/home/sin55/pub...', 512, Array)
#1 /home/sin55/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(512): is_file('/home/sin55/pub...')…